# How to use validations in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am facing a problem in form validation using Angular.js.

This is my HTML code:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="regForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':regForm.name.$touched && regForm.name.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Username:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter Username" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" required>
        </div>
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="regForm.name.$error" ng-if="regForm.name.$touched">
            <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
            <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
            <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pwd" ng-model="pwd" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$" maxlength="12" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Repeat Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control col-sm-6" type="password" name="num" ng-model="repeat password" placeholder="Repeat password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email Address:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input class="form-control col-sm-6" type="email" name="num" ng-model="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Repeat Email Address:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input class="form-control col-sm-6" type="email" name="num" ng-model="repeatemail" placeholder="Repeat Email Address">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

For the first input field (i.e. username) I tried validations using ng-messages and has-error. This was the output I am getting

[image]

I need the specific output be like, if name is small means I have to get error message like "your name is too small". But when I am typing the name I am getting three error messages at a time.

Comment: btw your code working too swati.. I copied and run your code it is showing 1 error at a time...

Comment: @Anil Kumar Ram no it is not working for me,when i used with ng-messages but it is working with ng-if.

Comment: May be u have not included all the libraries.. angular-message.js

Comment: @ Anil Kumar Ram ok thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the condition for each message to show:

`<p ng-if="regForm.name.$error.minlength">Your name is too short.</p>`

Comment: Please note this is not making use of the `angular-messages` module.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. I suspect you don't have the `angular-messages` module included. From the angular docs:

> First, get the file:
>
> Google CDN e.g. `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-messages.js`
>
> NPM e.g. `npm install angular-messages@X.Y.Z`
>
> Bower e.g. `bower install angular-messages#X.Y.Z`
>
> Then, include angular-messages.js in your HTML:
>
> `<script src="path/to/angular.js"></script>`
>
> `<script src="path/to/angular-messages.js"></script>`
>
> Finally, load the module
>   in your application by adding it as a dependent module:
>
> `angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);`
>
> With that you're ready to get started!